# Angularjs form scope bug

Tags: angularjs

I have a Angularjs form with a list with names.
When I click on a name the form will change with here profile.
When I change one input and don't save it and I click on a other profile every thing change except the one input that has changed.

```
<form class="form-horizontal bordered-row" >
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Naam</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="{{gegevens.naam | capitalize}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Categorie</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <select class="form-control">
                      <option ng-repeat="x in producten_categorie" value="{{x.value}}" ng-selected="gegevens.categorie == x.value">{{x.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group pad25L">
                  <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="productAlgemeen_update(gegevens.naam);">Save</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

And the change scope:

```
$scope.productGegevens = function(product){
$http.post("php/producten-locatie.php", {'id':product.id}).then(function(response){
  $scope.producten_locatie = response.data.records[0];
  $scope.gegevens = {
    id:product.id,
    naam:product.naam,
    categorie:product.categorie,
    straatnaam:$scope.producten_locatie.straatnaam,
    huisnummer:$scope.producten_locatie.huisnummer,
    postcode:$scope.producten_locatie.postcode,
    stadsnaam:$scope.producten_locatie.stadsnaam
  };
});
```

}

Comment: It looks like change detection is a problem. Can you share you ts class file

Comment: @AniruddhaDas I'm new in Angular, but what is ts class file? 
Everything will change when I press de change scope but except the one has changed, maybe because it is dirty?

Comment: Never mind I was thinking it's angular application but it angularjs.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas Sorry

Comment: you mean to say the changed value remains same and not reflecting correct value when we open other profile ?

Comment: Post code of click event on profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that input data needs to bind with ng-model whereas you are entering your input with value tag. it means the value is rendered in html not in model, so when you click on other profile UI can not detect the change. Please use ng-model for input value not value tag of input box.